# JavaScript/jQuery downloading PDF file returned from Django view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, django, pdf

I have a celery task that creates PDF files on the click of a button.

When the button is clicked, the javascript side will keep checking until the task is done, and when it is, it will download the file. I figured some recursivity would do:

```
$(".getPdf").on('click', function(event) {

    // Grab the clicked object ID and the filename stored on the data attributes
    var thisId = $(this).data('runid');
    var filename = $(this).data('filename');
    var taskID = "None";
    var pdfStatus = "None";

    // Run download function
    downloadPdf(filename, taskID, pdfStatus);
    function downloadPdf(filename, taskID, pdfStatus) {

        // Send a POST request to Django's RunsView with the Run ID, pdf filename, task ID and pdfStatus (if any)
        $.post({
            url: "{% url 'runs' %}",
            data: {
                csrfmiddlewaretoken: "{{ csrf_token }}",
                id: thisId,
                filename: filename,
                task_id: taskID,
            },
            success: function(data) {
                // Split the returned string to separate the task ID [0] from the status [1]
                var taskID = data.split(";")[0];
                var pdfStatus = data.split(";")[1];

                // Convert the pdfStatus Python bools into JavaScript bools
                if (pdfStatus == "False") {
                    pdfStatus = false;
                } else if (pdfStatus == "True") {
                    pdfStatus = true;
                };

                if (!pdfStatus) {
                    console.log("Repeat function.");
                    downloadPdf(filename, taskID, pdfStatus);
                } else {
                    console.log("Download PDF");
                    window.open("data:application/pdf;base64," + data);
                };
            },
            traditional: true
        }).done();
    };
});
```

The actual JavaScript side of the PDF download is simple enough. I send the ID of the object I want to generate a PDF of (a "**Run**"), along with the filename that it should have (this is generated on the **get** part of the same page's Django view), and an empty celery task ID (the task has not been created yet of course). The response I get back is a string made of "celery task ID;" with False if the task is not done yet, so I repeat the POST request.

On the backend side of things, I handle the POST request depending on if the task ID is present or not:

```
def post(self, request):
    # Get the args from the incoming request
    run_id = request.POST.get('id')
    filename = request.POST.get('filename')
    task_id = request.POST.get('task_id')

    if run_id and task_id == "None":

        # Database and Django stuff happens here for a few lines...

        # Fire off a Celery task to generate the PDF file asynchronously
        pdf_task = create_pdf.delay(sensor, range_period)
        response_string = str(pdf_task.task_id) + ";" + str(AsyncResult(pdf_task.task_id).ready())

        return HttpResponse(response_string)

    elif task_id != "None":
        pdf_done = AsyncResult(task_id).ready() # If this is false, send the task ID back with a False
        if not pdf_done:
            response_string = str(task_id) + ";" + str(pdf_done)
            return HttpResponse(response_string)
        # Otherwise send the PDF back
        else:
            pdf_task = AsyncResult(task_id)
            pdf_file = pdf_task.result
            pdf_file_location = settings.MEDIA_ROOT + '/reports/' + pdf_file


            # response = HttpResponse(content_type='application/pdf')
            # response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename={}'.format(pdf_task.result)
            # # return response

            try:
                # with open(pdf_file_location, 'r') as pdf:
                #   response = HttpResponse(pdf.read(), content_type='application/pdf')
                #   response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="' + pdf_task.result + '"'
                # pdf.close()
                return FileResponse(open(pdf_file_location, 'rb'), content_type='application/pdf')

            except IOError:
                print("File does not exist, check above.")

            return response
```

I've gone ahead and left in the attempts I made at making the file download work with the AJAX request. So far the one that's not commented out has actually returned a string of encoded text to the front end, but I'm not sure how to decode that, I end up with a tab that looks like this:

[image]

So the encoded PDF is reaching the front end after the file is done processing (that part is fine), but I'm not good enough at JavaScript to figure out how to turn the encoded string into a PDF file.

Answer (score 0):

You can decode base64 to Blob and download it as file.

```
var blob = new Blob(atob(data), {type: 'application/pdf'})

var link = document.createElement("a");
link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
link.download = "filename.pdf";
document.body.appendChild(link);
link.click()
```